# Update data dynamically

Tags: php

```
  public function update($id, $table, $data, $exclude = array()){

    $query = "UPDATE $table SET";

    $fields = $values = array();

    if( !is_array($exclude) ) $exclude = array($exclude);
    foreach( array_keys($data) as $key ) {

        if( !in_array($key, $exclude) ) {
            $fields[] = "`$key`";
            $values[] = "'" . $this->db->real_escape_string($data[$key]) . "'";
        }

        $fields = implode(" ", $fields);
        $values = implode(" ", $values);

        $query .= $fields . "=" . $values . ",";

    }

    $query = $query . "WHERE id = '".$id."' ";


      if(!$this->db->query($query)){
        echo "Something wrong with query ";

      }
      else{
        echo "successfully updated";
      }

  }
```

Got error

```
Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings
```

Tweaked code from add function which worked. Wanted to have fields and values updated dynamically without using variables, i.e. $_POST['address'].

```
 $query .= $fields . "=" . $values . ", ";
```

seem not to be working. Not sure what cause the error: Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings. How to insert field = value in sql query?

Comment: You implode the array inside foreach and update in the same variable so they change to string. `$fields = implode(" ", $fields);`, do it outside foreach, OR initialize `$fields = $values = array();` at the beginning of foreach.

Comment: Why people help you if you don't take the suggestion??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
  if( !is_array($exclude) ) $exclude = array($exclude);
    foreach( array_keys($data) as $key ) {
        if( !in_array($key, $exclude) ) {
            $query .= $key . "='" . $data[$key] . "' ,";
        }
    }
    $query = substr($query,0,strlen($query)-1);

    $query = $query . " WHERE id = '".$id."' ";
```

Comment: thanks but unfortunately, it doesn't show anything except that run query is failed.

Comment: yay thanks. I copied your substr line. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Look at the foreach loop!!!

```
foreach( array_keys($data) as $key ) {

    if( !in_array($key, $exclude) ) {
        $fields[] = "`$key`";
        $values[] = "'" . $this->db->real_escape_string($data[$key]) . "'";
    }

    $fields = implode(" ", $fields); // Mistake done here
    $values = implode(" ", $values); // Mistake done here

    $query .= $fields . "=" . $values . ","; 

}
```

Change your those two line and the next line outside the loop. May be this solve your problem.

```
foreach( array_keys($data) as $key ) {
    if( !in_array($key, $exclude) ) {
        $fields[] = "`$key`";
        $values[] = "'" . $this->db->real_escape_string($data[$key]) . "'";
    }       
}
$fields = implode(" ", $fields);
$values = implode(" ", $values);
$query .= $fields . "=" . $values . ",";
```

Comment: yeah thats what i did already before u posted. but it didn't work.

Comment: What;s the issue now??

Comment: Only that query failed.

Comment: May be the issue is here `$query = $query . "WHERE id = '".$id."' ";`, try to add one space before WHERE `$query = $query . " WHERE id = '".$id."' ";`

Comment: Are u angry or what? u put alot of ??? just test with echo sql error: Prepare failed: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`name` `address` `country` ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114588/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-joe).

Answer (score 1):

Follow my code. Where no need implementation `implode()` function. I have changed your function code. try it.

```
public function update($id, $table, $data, $exclude = array()){

    $query = "UPDATE $table SET";

    $fields = $values = array();

    if( !is_array($exclude) ) $exclude = array($exclude);
    foreach( array_keys($data) as $key ) {

        if( !in_array($key, $exclude) ) {
            $queryArr[] = $key . "='" . $this->db->real_escape_string($data[$key]);                
        }
    }  
    $query = implode(" ,", $queryArr);

    $query = $query . "WHERE id = '".$id."' ";    

      if(!$this->db->query($query)){
        echo "Something wrong with query ";

      }
      else{
        echo "successfully updated";
      }

  }
```

Comment: thanks. now sql error message: Prepare failed: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = '1'' at line 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713278/attempting-to-learn-mysqli-prepared-statements-what-am-i-doing-wrong

Comment: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/error-1064

Comment: thanks but I do not use prepare. haha. seems like something with syntax in query

Comment: Oh i see that comma is stuck at the end of WHERE. so how to remove comma when the field is last?